# Firing a relativistic kill missile at a god in an otherwise medieval world: How to Adjudicate?

Tags: system-agnostic, osr

My players have come up with a (deviously clever) solution to an impossible quest to kill a particular god-like being: accelerate an unobtanium missile at it to relativistic speeds and smash it into said god.  They have the missile in question and a method to accelerate it.

My trouble is this: how do I adjudicate a system for calculating the trajectory of such a missile in an otherwise medieval world?  I don't want to say

- "It hits, you calculate correctly."
- "It misses, there's no way you can do that calculation." (While this might be realistic, they presumably could get access to instruments precise enough to target a missile like this)
- "Give me your relativistic equations and I'll error check them" (This would be no fun for anyone, and I'd be in way over my head)
- "Make an attack roll/ability roll" (Doesn't give the thing the weight it needs, and is a bad ad-hoc solution anyhow)

My goal is this: **provide a ruling for calculating such a missile's trajectory (end result it hits or misses) that isn't overly reductive or as complex as the real thing it's representing.**

To reduce the scope of this question from the theoretically infinite rulings that could be made to something answerable with good subjective, bad subjective: What kind or ruling/system can I make that can engage all the players and give them a chance to affect the hit/miss outcome in a way driven by player interaction? (**only** a random roll or a character build option is undesriable)  How do I give this the weight it deserves without devolving into mind-numbing calculation?

Comment: We are going to need to know what game you are playing to answer this. Some game systems have rules for this, some have guidelines that can be used, and some would resort to GM rulings. If this is a system you have devised for yourself (or a heavily rules-light system), we will need to know as much as we can about the system to have an idea for how this should be handled.

Comment: @DavidCoffron It's a (relatively) rules light system based on OD&D; in this case, the thinking behind the system is more important than the system itself.  Because this system is highly modular and prone to one-off systems and rulings as well as player skill dependent, I thought it was best to mark this as OSR and System-Agonstic rather than any specific system.  I'll call this out more explicitly in my question.  I'm looking for something where the players interactions with the system (not just the characters abilities) have a high weight in determining outcome.

Comment: Okay, do you literally mean relativistic (that is, near the speed of light)? Because at that speed, unless we're calculating in astronomical units, trajectory has very little to do with the equation. I mean, gravity will still curve light but probably not enough to have a meaningful impact.

Comment: "How to adjudicate" is almost always going to require a specific system, because the answer is going to tell you how to translate the situation into the mechanical language of that system.

Comment: @WrongOnTheInternet so are you actually more asking us then to help you *create* a system that would allow you to achieve these goals? Are there any similar systems already implemented that your can tell us to help us understand how your game works already?

Comment: https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/ seems pertinent to the discussion at hand.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I'm more asking for a good set of principles to start working with on making my own system or a good ruling.  My question has basically been identifying things I don't want to do (and one trait I consider desirable in a system like this), but there's no solid design foundation to get started from.  I'm thinking I'd want to start with a system that starts with a success chance of 0, and increases based on the players doing *something*, but what those things would be isn't clear.  It may well be that this question is a poor fit for SE.

Comment: @BenBarden Funny enough, a different what-if gave me the information on speed / damage (much simpler to rule on).

Comment: @MarkWells In this case I'm more asking for principles to keep in mind when producing my own system or ruling, not for one to be produced for me.  The general approach in JoshuaD's (gradate outcome) is a good generalist approach.  This is more of a "how do I approach this design" question than "build me this specific system" question.

Comment: @MarkWells Put another way, I'm asking "How do I dig?", not "Suggest a shovel for me."  Answers suggesting to use a shovel would be more appropriate.

Comment: @WesleyObenshain I mean moving at some fraction the speed of light, accelerated over a long period of time.  Trajectory is important due to orbit and the time it takes to accelerate.

Comment: This seems to be asking for ideas for how to design this, which can’t have a right answer. This seems more like a subject for a forum discussion.

Comment: "relativistic", that's like the same speed as magic-missile and teleport, right?

Answer (score 6):

**Expand the Range of Possible Outcomes, and have the final result depend on how many tests/rolls the players can pass.**

Currently the result of the attack as you described is binary: either the attack succeeds and the god dies, or it fails and (presumably) the missile has no effect whatsoever.  As you pointed out, having such a massive thing hinge on one or two dice rolls is anti-climactic.

In order to give the attack more *gravitas*, make a range of possible outcomes, good and bad.  For example:

- The missile kills the god
- The missile misses completely, detonating harmlessly
- The missile injures and disables the god but doesn't kill it. (Does one of its nemeses now show up and finish the job, creating a bigger problem?)
- The missile kills the god but it also damages the universe/mulitverse/planes system.
- The missile doesn't kill the god, but it damages the world
- The missile harms the god, making it go into a rage destroying things.

etc.

After doing this, create a series of test/rolls that have be passed to get the best outcome, have alternative outcomes occur when less than all of the rolls/tests are passed.

In this way, it becomes a lot more like a combat type situation, where there are a series of rolls interwoven with narrative and decision making.

Make use of the skill system. Make use of the combat system. Make use of whatever frameworks the game system gives you, and weave them all together into one massive encounter as this missile is launched.

Maybe the fighter is holding off a horde of enemies as the nerd is preparing the missile and the rogue is hot-wiring the launcher.   Look at what skills your party has (and doesn't have) and make an encounter that challenges all of those abilities and skills, and create stepped results based on failures and successes.